# Shapes in dygraphs legend

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is it possible to add shapes in a dygraphs legend? Right now I'm working on making a graph with series that are related to each other, at the moment I'm able to represent each of the values in the graph with a color and a shape, this means each series has a color and a shape, so the series that share the same color or shape share something in common. The problem is that I'm only able to represent the color of the series in the legend when the series are defined by their specific  shape and color. Unfortunately I haven't found any option in the legend section that helps me display the specific shape for each of the series.

Comment: I would be very grateful with any input or feedback on this issue @danvk .

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to build dygraphs from HEAD, you can use the new [`legendFormatter`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683) option. This gives you complete control over the legend. Check out the PR description for details.